# how to show Tool Tip for disabled Textbox using Jquery

Tags: jquery

idea is expected for ToolTip for Disabled TextBox using Jquery

## Here is My Code

```
$("#<%=txt_RyotName_R.ClientID%>").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer').attr('title', $("#<%=txt_RyotName_R.ClientID%>").val());
}, function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `title` then bind the event handler.

```
$("#txt_RyotName_R")
  .attr('title', function(){
      return this.value;
  })
  .hover(function() {
     $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
  }, function() {
     $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
  });
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#txt_RyotName_R")
    .attr('title', function() {
      return this.value;
    })
    .hover(function() {
      $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    }, function() {
      $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt_RyotName_R" disabled value="some text">
```

Comment: @yuvi, Consider accepting the answer see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)